# How to find ALL text frames in InDesign by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scripting, frames, adobe-indesign

I need to find all text frames on the active page in an InDesign document and to put them into an array - in order to grab out one or many text frame(s) carrying a specific script label. I tried

```
myPage = app.properties.activeWindow && app.activeWindow.activePage,
myTextFrames = myPage.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();
```

but this doesn't bring those text frames that are -anchored; -in a table cell; -within a group. How can I get really all text frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in one line.

You may need to start from 
`myPage.allPageItems` --> which returns an array AND filter it by

1. `arrayElement.constructor.name == "TextFrame"`

or

2. `arrayElement.label == "yourTargetLabel"`

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Array of every single pageItem in the document
var myItems = doc.allPageItems;
var  n = myItems.length, tfs = [], nItem;

//Looping through page items to collect text frames
while ( n-- ) {
nItem = myItems[n];
(nItem instanceof TextFrame) && tfs.push ( nItem );
}

//result
alert( tfs.length + " textframes have been found" );
```

You may also go the other way around by working with stories:

```js
//Storing all stories in the document.
var stories = doc.stories.everyItem().getElements(), n = stories.length, nStory, tfs = [];

//looping through stories to collect text frames
while ( n-- ) {
 nStory = stories[n];
 tfs.concat ( nStory.textContainers );
}
//result
alert( tfs.length + " textframes have been found" );
```

This might help.